# Why I got different maven result between Windows and MacOS in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a strange problem when I update Maven project in Eclipse between Windows and MacOS.

In Windows, I can see the source file of this jar file, but I can't see the source in MacOS. The Maven setting should be the same.

[image: Image of differences]

The left side are the files I get after I update Maven project on MacOS and the right side are file as the result of Maven update in Windows, they are different.

Actually, when I replace the Windows's content to MacOS, I did see the source in my Eclipse project, but it's gone after I update Maven project again!

Are there some maven setting I need to set to make the update got the the result? Why am I getting a different result between the two OS?

Is there something I missed? Please give me some hints, thank you~~

Eric

Comment: First you say...the maven settings should be same? Are they really are? Furthermore using Maven from plain command line? Using the same maven version and the same plugin versions ?

Comment: And are IDE settings same? Can you confirm "Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Download Artifact Sources" ?

Comment: What is different, exactly?

Comment: Also, this is a `SNAPSHOT` dependency, so normally it is not shared via central repos. From which repo do you get it?

Comment: My maven version is 3.3.9/1.8.0(Win, EMBEDDED) and 3.3.9/1.8.2(Mac, EMBEDDED), I have check the maven setting page by page, only the settings with path information are different. (Dues to OS's file system rule.) The Download Artifact Sources doesn't selected in both platform. I have try to enable this option in Mac, but got the same result.

Comment: The repo is our company 's private library. It's owned by ourself. The strange thing is the project update's result is different in Mac/Win.